# Binary matrices with constant row and column sums

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices, terminology

My question is about $m \times n$ binary matrices (aka $\{0,1\}$-matrices), whose rows all sum to the same value, and whose columns all sum to the same value (but these two values may be different).

The first question is simply: is there a standard name for such matrices? They correspond to the biadjacency matrices of so-called "biregular bipartite graphs", but this terminology doesn't appear to be commonly used.

Second, are there any "interesting" constructions of families of such matrices, in particular that are connected to other combinatorial objects?

Two simple examples of constructions of these matrices are the $\binom{n}{k} \times n$ matrix whose rows consist of every $n$-bit string with Hamming weight $k$; and the $2^n \times 2^n$ [Sylvester-Hadamard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix#Sylvester.27s_construction) matrices with the first row and column removed.

I did find a [paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(80)90105-6) by Brualdi titled "Matrices of Zeros and Ones with Fixed Row and Column Sum Vectors", but this seems to be more concerned with the question of existence of these matrices, rather than constructing them.

Comment: As to the name, a Google search, and a glance to the references in the papers, confirm that the long but self-explicatory combination that you used in the title is very popular.

Comment: Indeed, the columns ${\bf must}$ sum to a different value than the rows, unless $m=n$ (or the common sum is zero). There is some discussion of these matrices in Ryser's little book on Combinatorial Mathematics. 

Comment: You should investigate papers of A. Barvinok on contingency tables.

Comment: In case of symmetric square matrices and equal row sum and column sum these matrices correspond to the adjacency matrices of regular graphs; admittedly a rather trivial remark.
Another trivial remark is that hese matrices represent solutions to specific assignment problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your question about interesting combinatorial objects: Your Sylvester-Hadamard matrix example generalizes in at least two ways.

1. The incidence matrix of any balanced incomplete [block design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design) or, more generally, $t$-design has constant row and column sums.  Specifically, a BIBD$(v,b,r,k,\lambda)$ represented as a $v\times b$ incidence matrix has row sums $r$ and column sums $k$.  Normalizing an $n\times n$ Hadamard matrix so that the first row and column consist entirely of 1s, and then removing this row and column while replacing $-1$s with 0s gives a design with parameters $v=b=n-1$, $r=k=n/2-1$, $\lambda=n/4-1$.  So among Hadamard matrices, Sylvester-Hadamard matrices are not special in this regard.  Finite projective planes are also designs, with parameters $v=b=q^2+q+1$, $r=k=q+1$, $\lambda=1$, where $q$ is the order of the plane.
2. Sylvester-Hadamard matrices have the additional property that if the first row and column are removed, and the remaining rows and columns are suitably permuted, one obtains a circulant matrix.  (Most Hadamard matrices do not have this property, but Paley-Hadamard matrices constructed using quadratic residues in $\mathbb{F}_p$, $p\equiv3\pmod{4}$ also do.  More generally, Hadamard matrices constructed from [difference sets](https://www.dmgordon.org/diffset/) do.)  But any $n\times n$ circulant matrix whatsoever will have constant row and column sums (with row sums equal to column sums).  (This is not combinatorially so interesting in general.)

**Addendum:** In answer to your first question, design theorists call an incidence structure whose incidence matrix has constant row and column sums a **tactical configuration**.  This is a $t$-design with $t=1$.  The balanced incomplete block designs in the first part of my answer are $t$-designs with $t=2$, but any $t$-design is also a $(t-1)$-design.  The condition that any two points be incident with exactly $\lambda$ blocks gives BIBDs a lot of additional interesting structure that tactical configurations do not typically have.  3-, 4-, and 5-designs are more interesting still.  See the [PlanetMath page](https://planetmath.org/incidencestructure) for more information.

**Added 12 July  2022:** I just updated the link above to the La Jolla Difference Set Repository, which is now the La Jolla Combinatorics Repository. Dan Gordon's slides [here](http://www.cargo.wlu.ca/ArasuFest/ArasuFest_talks/Dan_Gordon.pdf) have examples showing how to query the database.

Comment: Here is at least a [Wayback Machine snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20101218171117/http://www.ccrwest.org/diffsets/diff_sets/index.html) of the difference sets repository linked in the answer. I am not sure what would be good replacement for that dead link - it seems that [D. Gordon has some database with this topic](https://www.dmgordon.org/diffset/).

Comment: @MartinSleziak If I'm not mistaken, the old La Jolla Difference Set Repository was also Dan Gordon's work. I would guess the database you link to is the successor of that one. It seems less browsable than the old version, although I must admit it's been years since I used it, so I may be misremembering. The slides [here](http://www.cargo.wlu.ca/ArasuFest/ArasuFest_talks/Dan_Gordon.pdf), starting on page 9, show how to enter search terms to generate various tables.

Answer (score 9):

If you fix $m,n$ and the row and column values, and then consider the matrices as points in $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$,  their convex hull forms a convex polytope known as a *transportation polytope*. In the particular case of permutation matrices one obtains the famous [Birkhoff polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff_polytope) for instance.

So I would advise you to look up references about those polytopes, since your matrices arise naturally as their vertices; hopefully you can find the names and particular constructions you asked for.

(Well this this should probably be a comment, since I do not really answer any of your questions; unfortunately I do not have enough magic points to write one)

**Edit:**  As pointed out in a comment, what I wrote above is simply not true. In fact, the $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$-matrices considered are more precisely the lattice points of the intersection of a transportation polytope with the hypercube $[0,1]^{mn}$; this forms another polytope which may actually be interesting in its own right.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice alternative way to look at these matrices.

Comment: "Magic points" -- I love it!

Comment: "your matrices arise naturally as their vertices": this isn't true due to the restriction to (0,1) matrices. For example, let

`$$A=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}, B=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 2\\ 2 & 0\\ \end{pmatrix}, C=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix},$$`

then the row and column sums of $A,B,C$ are equal to 2, but $C=1/2(A+B),$ so $C$ is not a vertex of the corresponding transportation polytope. You can impose (0,1) restriction by force, but I think that the resulting polytopes would be quite different from the standard transportation polytopes. 

Comment: Victor: you're absolutely right of course, I'll edit my so-called answer...

Comment: @Phillipe,  Philippe, could you expound a little on "transportation polytopes"? Wikipedia has nothing, and the google search led to papers about the "20 year history of ..." etc. Are they akin or similar to stochastic matrices describing the probabilistic evolution of a Markov chain? When limited to zeros and ones, are they just a permutation matrix? Please forgive me if my question seems stupid. I am familiar with stochastic matrices, but not "transportation polytopes".

Comment: Fix $v\in \mathbb{R_+}^m$ and $w\in \mathbb{R_+}^n$. The transportation polytope $T(v,w)$ is the set of matrices of size $m\times n$ with nonnegative entries whose row sums are given by $v$ and column sums given by $w$. If $m=n$ and $v,w$ consist of ones you get bistochatic matrices, which form the Birkhoff polytope.

Answer (score 4):

About your first question: remark that when $m=n$ these matrices are sometimes called "semi-magic squares" (like "magic squares" but without the "sums along the diagonals" condition).

About the constructions of families of such matrices, there is another paper by Brualdi:

*R.A. Brualdi, Algorithms for constructing (0, 1)-matrices with prescribed row and column sum vectors, Discrete Math. 306 (2006), no. 23, 3054-3062.*

You can see also this paper by Fonseca and Mamede on the same subject:

http://www.mat.uc.pt/~cmf/papers/01matrix_fonseca_mamede.pdf

Here the construction is related to other combinatorial objects (pairs of semi-standard Young tableaux of conjugate shapes), as you wished.

Comment: Thanks; this connection to other types of object is indeed the sort of thing I was looking for.

Comment: The link in the answer seems to be dead - possibly the paper is C.M. da Fonseca, RicardoMamede: [On (0, 1)-matrices with prescribed row and column sum vectors](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=fonseca+mamede+matrices), DOI: [10.1016/j.disc.2008.06.013](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2008.06.013).

Answer (score 3):

See [this paper](https://doi.org/10.37236/1926) by Canfield and McKay. As the title suggests it focuses
on the asymptotic enumeration, but it has lots of useful references.

**Added** A simple arithmetic construction that realizes all possible
constant line sums is as follows. Let $g=\gcd(m,n)$. Label rows and
columns by elements of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$
respectively. Fix $0\le s\ge g$. Put a $1$ in each position $(j+k,j)$
where $j$ runs through $\mathbb{Z}$ and $0\le k < s$, interpreting
$j+k$ and $j$ as integers modulo $m$ and $n$ respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the link; some of those references were useful. In particular, the term "semi-regular bipartite graph" seems to be yet another way of describing these matrices.

Answer (score 0):

An $m \times m$ matrix of this type is called a **stochastic matrix** if the sum of each of its rows is 1 (a **right** stochastic matrix) or if the sum of each of its columns is 1 (a **left** stochastic matrix).  A doubly-stochastic matrix has the sums of rows and the sums of columns equal to one.   A stochastic matrix is also called a transition matrix as it can represent the transition probabilities of a **Markov chain** over a finite state space $s$, where in this case $|s|=m$.

Each element of such a stochastic matrix is restricted to be $x_{i,j} \in \mathbb{R}, x_{i,j}>0$.  Thus in the case of stochastic matrices, since you are asking about binary matrices, every matrix entry is either zero or one: $x_{i,j} \in \{0,1\}$.   This restricts the sum to being $1$, and this type of stochastic binary matrix is also known as a **permutation matrix** as it represents the transitions in a permutation on a finite state space.

Answer (score 0):

build the matrix $H =(A-J)/2$ from your matrix $A.$
If this new matrix is hadamard and satisfy your condition 
$H$ it is called ``regular hadamard",  ((google this)).

$J$ is the matrix with only $1$ everywhere.

luis
$* * *$

Answer (score 0):

Read these articles about the topic:

Newman, M. (1978). Combinatorial Matrices with Small Determinants. Canadian Journal of Mathematics, 30(4), 756-762. [doi:10.4153/CJM-1978-065-8](https://doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1978-065-8)

http://ac.els-cdn.com/0024379578900769/1-s2.0-0024379578900769-main.pdf?_tid=ad812dd8-df9d-11e2-9fa1-00000aab0f27&acdnat=1372388089_8c2c33dc0172c0033cf87e6eb57c54df

Comment: The 1st link leads to a page where we read, "The Canadian Mathematical Society (CMS) has entered into a publishing partnership with Cambridge University Press (Cambridge). The web site for CJM is now hosted on Cambridge Core."

Comment: A currently active URL for the 1st paper is https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/combinatorial-matrices-with-small-determinants/F68B31A82986DFAA6E6A52FBC70A41EE The paper is Morris Newman, Combinatorial matrices with small determinants, and the DOI is  https://doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1978-065-8

Comment: The 2nd link doesn't lead anywhere, and I can't decipher the URL to work out where it was supposed to go. If OP is still here, maybe he could help out by editing in the author, title, journal, volume, year, and pages.