# Creating $p$ intersecting sets of $q$ equally distributed integers between $1$ and $r$

Tags: co.combinatorics

I am encountering the following problem :

Given $p$, $q$, and $r$, is there a way of creating $p$ sets of $q$ integers between $1$ and $r$, such that :

-every integer must be in exactly $\frac{pq}{r}$ sets

-all possible pairs of sets must intersect

I am trying to prove that this is impossible for certain values of $p$, $q$ and $r$, but I need to use every condition, forgetting one of them is never enough. Would you have any ideas on what would be eventually a necessary and sufficient condition on $p$, $q$ and $r$, or an equivalent but easier way to express the problem ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is an element belonging to at least $p(p-1)/2r$ pairs of sets, thus necessary condition is that $pq(pq-r)/2r^2\ge p(p-1)/2r$, $q(pq-r)\ge r(p-1)$, $r\le pq^2/(p+q-1)$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thank you. I actually saw this one, unfortunately it is not enough in my case. I feel like we are considering that each of the intersecting pairs provided by the elements are independent while they are linked by the fact that each set has $q$ elements.

Comment: Look up balanced incomplete block designs.  That or a minor variation should apply, and you will see some necessary conditions on the parameters.  Gerhard "Block Designs Clear The Way" Paseman, 2017.03.20.

Comment: Also, since every two blocks have an element in common, you might be considering a combinatorial  projective plane.  The Handbook of Combinatorial Designs should help.  Gerhard "Handing It Over To Handbooks" Paseman, 2017.03.20.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Thanks a lot, I will look it up !

Comment: Here is an equivalent formulation: You are looking for $(0,1)$-matrices of size $r\times p$ such that (1) every row has sum $pq/r$, (2) every column has sum $q$, and (3) no two columns are orthogonal. http://mathoverflow.net/q/36642/12674 might be relevant.

Comment: Interpreting the matrix as the adjacency matrix of a graph gives the following: Given $p$, $q$ and $r$, does there exist a bipartite graph $G=(A\cup B,E)$ with parts of size $|A|=r$ and $|B|=p$ such that (1) every vertex in $A$ has degree $pq/r$, (2) every vertex in $B$ has degree $q$, and (3) the distance between any two vertices in $A$ is 2.

Comment: The graph formulation gives the necessary condition $pq(q-1)\geqslant r(r-1)$ (I did not check if that's implied by Fedor's conditions).

Comment: @ThomasKalinowski Thank you for the help, I'll explore the equivalent formulations. The last necessary condition is still not enough unfortunately.